# Why isn't my if/else statement producing the desired results?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm having an issues with my program. I've practically completed it but the very end does not work as it should. I've written it two ways, one with a switch statement and also with an if else statement but neither works right. They both compile for me and have a clean build but will not run as it is supposed to.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdio>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{

    int i = 0;
    const int size = 27;
    char newline = '\n';
    char *pnumber = 0;
    int selection = 0;

    cout << "PRINGING CONTENTS OF ARRAY" << endl;
    cout << "====================================================" << endl;
    char alphabet[size] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'
    , 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y'
    , 'Z' , 0 };

     for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         cout << alphabet[i] << " ";
     }

     cout << newline;
     cout << newline;
     cout << "This is the title to your Program related to the alphabet."
     << endl;
     cout << endl;
     cout << "Select the index that coincides with the alphabet." << endl;
     cout << "For example, the number 7 should display the letter G" << endl;
     cout << endl;
     cout << "Enter an index between 1 and 26: ";
     cin >> i;
     cout << "The number you selected: " << i;
     cout << newline;
     cout << "The letter at this index: " << alphabet[i - 1];
     cout << endl;
     cout << newline;
     cout << newline;
     cout << "PRINTING CONTENTS OF ARRAY and adding x to every other element" << endl;
     pnumber = &alphabet[1];

     for (i = 0; i < size; i += 1)
     {
         if (i % 2 == 0)
         {
             cout << alphabet[i] << " ";
         }
    else
         {
             cout << "x ";
         }
     }

     cout << newline;
     cout << newline;

     cout << "PRINTING CONTENTS OF ARRAY USING THE MOD Option" << endl;
     cout << "=========================================================" << endl;
     cout << "Do you want the letters of the alphabet starting from index 0, A, or index 1, B: ";
     cin >> selection;
      switch (selection)
     {
         case 0:
         {
             for (i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
             {
                 cout << "Even Numbered Elements=" << i << " ";
                 cout << "Contents of Element within Array is=" << alphabet[i];
                 break;
             }
         }
         case 1:
         {
             for (i = 1; i < size; i += 2)
             {
                 cout << "Odd Numbered Elements=" << i << " ";
                 cout << "Contents of Element within Array is=" << alphabet[i] << endl;
                 break;
         }
     }
     default: cout << "You entered an invalid esponse.";
     }
     cout << endl;
     return 0;
 } //End of Int Main
```

The last part done with if else is this:

```
cout << newline;
cout << newline;

cout << "PRINTING CONTENTS OF ARRAY USING THE MOD Option" << endl;
cout << "=========================================================" << endl;

cout << "Do you want the letters of the alphabet starting from index 0, A, or index 1, B: ";
cin >> selection;

if (selection = 0){
    for (i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
    {
        cout << "Even Numbered Elements=" << i << " ";
        cout << "Contents of Element within Array is=" << alphabet[i] << endl;
    }
}
else{
    for (i = 1; i < size; i += 2)
    {
        cout << "Odd Numbered Elements=" << i << " ";
        cout << "Contents of Element within Array is=" << alphabet[i] << endl;
    }
}
return 0;
} //End of Int Main
```

1)The first part outputs the alphabet, 2)next it prompts for a number and is supposed to give the correlating letter, 3)next the program is supposed to output with every other letter being x such as A x C x E x........4)lastly it is supposed to prompt the user to select o to start the alphabet at A or 1 and start it B, then it would output every other letter. The last part doesn't work. It does not give the option but rather does the same each time. I've tweaked it other ways and it will do one or the other both times rather one or the other. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Increasing your warning level should catch this error.

Comment: Just write `'\n'` when you want to end a line. That `newline` is pointless, and `std::endl` does much more than you need.

Answer (score 5):

For second part change

```
if (selection = 0){
```

to

```
if (selection == 0){
```

Expression `selection = 0` is an assignment, but you need comparison.

Moreover, for checking evenness you can use `%` operator. E.g.:

```cpp
      if (selection % 2 == 0)
      {
           // if even
      }
      else
      {
           // if odd
      }
```

**EDIT:**

To avoid such mistypes in the future train yourself to write constant value on the left side of comparison operator, e.g.

```
 if (0 == selection)
```

and if you mistype compiler will show you error about l-value, that mast be variable.

**EDIT 2 (about switch and for):**

In the following code

```cpp
switch (selection)
{
   case 0:
         {
             for (i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
             {
                 cout << i << " ";
                 break;
             }
         }
    case 1:
     ...
}
```

`break` statement refers to the `for`, but not to `switch`, and as a result:

1) `for` will be executed only once;

2) while `selection` is `0` `case 1` will work after `case 0` anyway.

Correct code must be as follows

```cpp
switch (selection)
{
   case 0:
         {
             for (i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
             {
                 cout << i << " ";
             }
             break;
         }
    case 1:
     ...
}
```

Comment: Upvoting for the tip.

Comment: I am surprised that the compiler did not give a 'did you mean this?' warning. Also that tip reduces readability.

Comment: Am I better of with the if else statement then?

Comment: @EricWood It is up to you. As for me, you `switch` looks very strange (because `break;` is inside for-loop)

Comment: @EricWood And one more advice: make the prompt for `selection` variable input more clear, e.g. "Please, enter 0 if you want .... and enter other value if ...."

Comment: I got it with the if statement thank you so much I had considered the idea of using == I don't know why I didn't sooner.

Comment: @EricWood So, is the answer accepted?

Comment: Everything went well.

Answer (score 0):

Please do the change #

```
if (selection == 0)
```

I think the above mentioned change can remove the problem. In your code you are not comparing but assigning 0 in it and so never hopefully if gets executed and putting assignment in if is not the standard.

Hope this will help.